# Constricting mouse to canvas area in a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to write my own crop function so I can select an area from a larger image and then perform some other operations on it. I use matplotlib to import and display images: `self.img=plt.imread("someimage.png")`

If I stay in the canvas area this works fine:

```
 def __onclick__(self, event):

    self.point=[]
    if event.xdata is not None:
        xholder=event.xdata
    else:
        xholder = 0
    if event.ydata is not None:
        yholder = event.ydata
    else:
        yholder = 0 
    self.point.append([int(xholder),int(yholder)])
def __onrelease__(self,event):
    if event.xdata is not None:
        xholder=event.xdata
    else:
        xholder = self.img.shape[0]
    if event.ydata is not None:
        yholder = event.ydata
    else:
        yholder = self.img.shape[1]
    self.point.append([int(xholder),int(yholder)])
    self.plotcanvas.axes.imshow(self.img[self.point[0][1]:self.point[1][1],self.point[0][0]:self.point[1][0]])
    self.plotcanvas.draw()
```

However as soon as I go outside the canvas bounds `event.xdata` and `event.ydata` return (None,None). Is there anyway to constrict the mouse movements to only the area of the canvas once a mouse click is registered in the area of the canvas?

**EDIT with code that allows to import a .png file and then crop it**

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
import numpy as np


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):           
        self.statusBar()
        self.form_widget=FormWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)
        openFile = QtGui.QAction('Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Open new File')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        toolbar.addAction(openFile)
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):

        fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 
                '/home')

        self.form_widget.redraw(fname)

class FormWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):        
        super(FormWidget,self).__init__() 
        self.layout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mpcanvas=MyMplCanvas(self)
        self.plotcanvas=MyMplCanvas(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.plotcanvas)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mpcanvas)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.cidpresscsv=self.mpcanvas.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.__onclick__)
        self.cidreleasecsv=self.mpcanvas.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.__onrelease__)
    def redraw(self,fname):
        self.mpcanvas.axes=self.mpcanvas.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.img=plt.imread(fname)
        self.mpcanvas.axes.imshow(self.img)
        self.mpcanvas.draw()
    def __onclick__(self, event):
        self.point=[]
        if event.xdata is not None:
            xholder=event.xdata
        else:
            xholder = 0
        if event.ydata is not None:
            yholder = event.ydata
        else:
            yholder = 0
        self.point.append([int(xholder),int(yholder)])
    def __onrelease__(self,event):
        if event.xdata is not None:
            xholder=event.xdata
        else:
            xholder = self.img.shape[0]
        if event.ydata is not None:
            yholder = event.ydata
        else:
            yholder = self.img.shape[1]
        self.point.append([int(xholder),int(yholder)])
        self.plotcanvas.axes.imshow(self.img[self.point[0][1]:self.point[1][1],self.point[0][0]:self.point[1][0]])
        self.plotcanvas.draw()




class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.fig.tight_layout()
        self.axes.hold(False)
        self.compute_initial_figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass



def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is what came out after cutting out all the unnecessary stuff and still make a functional program that lets you import a .png file and then croup out an area out of it. I am sure that Rectangle selector proposed by Ed Smith might work, but I had trouble getting the example code to work and was confused about where the values were stored and how eclick and erelease worked in context with other event handlers. I'm afraid I am not that well versed in matplotlib and python in general.

Comment: Just a thought - you could also handle the `figure_leave_event` and set the corner of the rectangle to that if the mouse leaves the canvas.  You might have to introduce a temporary store of the corner, rather than simply appending it to `self.point`.  Then, if the mouse re-enters, you probably need to revert to current function.  If you give a bit more context (i.e. a barebones view of the class within which your functions sit) and my suggestion sounds useful, I'll write up as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The box selector matplotlib [widget](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector%20which%20automatically%20limits%20the%20box%20to%20the%20canvas%20bounds.) may be the easiest way to go. You can use the code with the image you have:

```
from matplotlib.widgets import  RectangleSelector
from pylab import *

def onselect(eclick, erelease):
  'eclick and erelease are matplotlib events at press and release'
  print ' startposition : (%f, %f)' % (eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata)
  print ' endposition   : (%f, %f)' % (erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata)
  print ' used button   : ', eclick.button

def toggle_selector(event):
    print ' Key pressed.'
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print ' RectangleSelector deactivated.'
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print ' RectangleSelector activated.'
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

fig = figure
ax = subplot(111)

A = np.random.random((30,30))
ax.imshow(A)
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, onselect, drawtype='box')
connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
show()
```

Although the mouse isn't limited to the box, the default behaviour when `minspanx` and `minspany` are `None` is to limit the returned coordinates to the box. I don't think you could easily limit mouse movements to a canvas.